# Form validation combined with isolated directive is deleting scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

When I combine a directive with isolate scope with custom validation, the validation sets my `scope` value to `undefined` when the validation fails.

Here's a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/5mKU3/7/

The html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="example">
        someModel: {{someValue}}<br>
        <input type="text" isolate ng-model="someValue" validate />
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('isolate', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {}
    };
}).directive('validate', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                value = value || '';

                if (value.length < 10) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('fail', true);
                    return value;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('fail', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}).controller('example', function ($scope) {
    $scope.someValue = '1234';
});
```

The validation fails when the input exceeds 10 characters. How do I make it so when validation fails, the `$scope.someValue` doesn't get reset to `undefined`?

The version of angular that I am currently on is 1.2.18.

Comment: so your code is saying right now..."if it doesn't fail...set validity...and then return undefined" does that last part where you are returning `undefined` have any bearing on your `$scope` variable being undefined after a failure?

Comment: i guess - if you don't want it reset...why not just `return value` there - maybe this isnt your problem...but i know angular fairly well if you want to explain further i might be able to help further

Comment: @ewizard per the docs for `ngModelController`, "For validation, the parsers should update the validity state using $setValidity(), and return undefined for invalid values." I imagine this is so it doesn't update the value on the `scope` to something you don't want...?

Comment: This is the exact same thing you'll see if you use the built-in `ng-maxlength="10"`. All the built-in validation works like that, and to be honest I think it's a good idea to have the model value be `undefined`. Why would you want an invalid value in your model?

Comment: @ivarni True, but an unwanted side effect is that it's setting `$scope.someValue` to `undefined`. If `ng-maxlength` behaves the same, why would you want it to delete your user's input when they have exceeded the limit you have set for them? Shorting the amount of characters so that it matches the limit makes sense, but deleting it altogether does not.

Comment: The input isn't deleted, it's still there in the input-box. On the screen. In plain view. It's the underlying *model* that don't have a value, and that is a good thing. Knowing that your model is always either empty or valid is a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [`ngModelOptions.allowInvalid`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) to `true`.

Your input would be like:

`<input type="text" isolate ng-model="someValue" validate ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}"/>`

Verify this info at [`$validate()` method's description](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)